# Type theory vs higher-order logic

Tags: logic, terminology, foundations, type-theory, higher-order-logic

This is a question about terminology, as I am clearly confused on the topic.

The Wikipedia page on [higher-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_logic) defines it as follows:

> Higher-order logic is the union of first-, second-, third-, …, nth-order logic; i.e., higher-order logic admits quantification over sets that are nested arbitrarily deeply.

So this is worded vaguely. Taken at face value, it says that higher-order logic is the union of all logics up to some arbitrary $n$. This would imply that higher-order logic is not one thing, but that for each $n$ there is a higher-order logic, so that higher-order logic is sort of just a catch-all term for logic of some order > 2, or what have you.

But then it says that higher-order logic admits quantification over arbitrary-order predicates, which one could interpret as being the union of first-, second-, third-, ... order logic without stopping at *any* $n$, meaning quantifiers of all orders are included. However, this does not imply that there are "infinite-order" predicates that can simultaneously quantify over *all* finite-order predicates, just that you can have arbitrarily large finite-order predicates.

Then on [this Stanford page](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/#4), it says under "Higher-Order Logic" that $\omega$-order logic is "type theory," with continuation into the transfinite being conceivable.

Is the correct idea that higher-order logic has all quantifiers of finite order, each of which quantifiers over all predicates up to a certain order type, whereas type theory has infinite-order quantifiers enabling you to quantify over *all* finite-order predicates?

Comment: This paper (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S157086830700081X) describing type theory also calls it higher-order logic. Every variable in it belongs to a definite order, so quantifiers only quantify over predicates of a certain order, not the union of predicates of different orders.

Comment: I guess this is "simple" type theory, which they distinguish from Russell's ramified type theory. It seems to be different from the way I see type theory described elsewhere.

Comment: Most versions of "type theory" I've seen are *syntactically* expressed as first-order theories, even though they have the ability to express higher-order logic concepts.  Much the same way ZFC is a first-order theory, and yet you can express for example second-order statements such as completeness of $\mathbb{R}$: $\forall S \subseteq \mathbb{R}, (\exists y \in \mathbb{R}, \forall x \in S, x \le y) \rightarrow \cdots$.  The point is this is a first-order statement in ZFC, which is equivalent to a second-order statement in the language of models of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sure, but I'm deliberately diving into higher-order logic here, so trying to avoid first-order "reductions" of common theories (which are often limited)...

Comment: There is nothing vague about the Wikipedia definition apart from the fact that (in context) the article is defining the language of higher-order logic to be the union of the languages of $n$-th order logic for all $n$. What's wrong with that?

Comment: It's vague specifically because it doesn't say the union for all n, it says the union up to some n. It's like the difference between $f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + ... + f(n)$ and $f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + ...$. As this notation is commonly used, the latter is understood to continue forever as an infinite series, the former is finitely long and has $n$ terms.

Comment: If you are just complaining about the wording of the Wikipedia article, you should take that up on Wikipedia. You are also reading too much into the Standard article, the $\omega$-order logic discussed there is exactly the same as what the Wikipedia article means (but doesn't quite describe correctly), i.e., the union $\bigcup_{n \in \omega} \cal L_n$ where $\cal L_n$ is the language of $n$-th order logic. This doesn't allow a single quantifier to range over predicates of all orders. As the Stanford article says, there are conceivable extensions, but that's not what they are talking about.

Comment: What I'm doing is asking what the terms "higher-order logic" and "type theory" mean in the literature. That's it. You seem to be claiming that higher-order logic is the union of all finite-order logics. Is type theory the same thing? Is it different?

Comment: I am just trying to help you make sense of the two references you mention. Church's simple type theory and higher-order logic (in the sense of the Wikipedia article) are equivalent and both can be viewed as the union of a family of finite-order logics. But there are many other type theories and many generalisations of higher-order logic. So your question as phrased ("is the correct idea that ...?") isn't really answerable in general. It can only be answered in the context of a specific system.

Comment: Thanks - when you refer to Church's simple type theory you are referring to what is called the [simply type lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_typed_lambda_calculus) on Wikipedia, correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While they don't own the term, the HOL family of mechanized proof assistants ([HOL4](https://hol-theorem-prover.org/), [HOL Light](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jrh13/hol-light/), [Isabelle/HOL](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/documentation.html)) is highly successful and influential. These are all implementations of (extensions of) simple type theory as described by [this paper](http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/sqrl/papers/SQRLreport18_rev2.pdf) referenced on the HOL4 site. The most significant extension that applies to all of them is that they use a polymorphic typed lambda calculus and not purely a simply typed lambda calculus.

While "type theory" nowadays usually means systems based on typed lambda calculi or the study thereof, to the extent that it is being contrasted to HOL, it is likely to mean specifically *dependently* typed lambda calculi. Even more specifically, it often means a descendant of [Intuitionistic or Martin-Löf Type Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_type_theory) (ITT). Again, there are highly successful and influential implementations of these, most notably [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/) and the LF-family including [Twelf](http://twelf.org/wiki/Main_Page). Dependently typed lambda calculi generalize simply typed lambda calculi (and in practice, often generalize polymorphic lambda calculi as well), so something like HOL is, roughly speaking, a sub-language of ITT. However, these systems are used in dramatically different ways. In HOL, a proposition is literally a Boolean expression and the goal is to show that it is the true Boolean. In ITT, a [propositions-as-types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence) perspective is typically taken so that a proposition is modeled as a type and the goal is to produce a value of that type.

People usually don't mean Russell's theory of types unless they are talking about the early history of formal logic. "Higher order logic" could possibly also be used simply as a contrast to first-order logic, i.e. as "not-first-order logic" and in that sense second-order logic would be a "higher order logic", but people rarely talk about third- or fourth-order logic, so they'd be likely to specifically refer to second-order logic where most of the good and bad things that come with moving beyond first-order logic have already occurred.

Comment: Thanks - I think the problem is that there are so many different type theories that I'm having trouble keeping them all straight. Let's consider the simply typed lambda calculus, which I think is what people have called "simple type theory," which I think means not dependently typed. Is the idea that HOL is equivalent to this simple STT, and the dependent types extend it? If so, how do I convert between HOL and STT?

Comment: To clarify, by HOL, I just mean the system that I was talking about with Rob Arthan in my original comments, not the proof system mentioned above.

Comment: [The Seven Virtues of Simple Type Theory](http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/sqrl/papers/SQRLreport18_rev2.pdf) which I linked above describes the embedding of $n$th-order logics into STT and states (but does not further prove) a theorem that the embeddings are faithful. Furthermore, the embedding does not rely on definite description for the "usual" connectives. Ignoring definite description (or targeting a logic with it), the only tricky part about going the other way is handling abstraction of functions which we can either encode as functional relations or disallow with a minor tweak.

Comment: As a field, the situation for type theory is similar to the situation for logic. (I don't even consider them separate fields.) Most type theories have a corresponding logic and vice versa. If you find the landscape of type theory confusing you should *also* find the landscape of logic confusing. If you don't, it's only due to the excessive focus on classical first-order logic. A small but important part of the type theory landscape is described by the [lambda cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_cube). This illustrates the relationships between STT, dependent type theory and CoC.

Comment: Thanks - I definitely hear you on that the two fields are in a similar state. Right now I understand quite a bit about classical logic, and am just trying to figure out the basic fundamentals of how this translates over into type theory. I read that paper before but hadn't caught the embedding - will check it out. Thank you!

Comment: OK, I see how to embed HOL predicates into STT now. First-order unary predicates are described by the type $(\iota \to \ast)$, where $\iota$ is the type of individuals and $\ast$ is the boolean type. Then, for n-ary first order predicates, we just Curry them: a binary first-order predicate becomes $(\iota \to (\iota \to \ast))$, and so on for predicates of higher arity. (cont'd)

Comment: Second-order predicates are also easy: for example, a second order predicate that evaluates unary first-order predicates would be of type $((\iota \to \ast) \to \ast)$, one that evaluates binary first-order predicates is of type $((\iota \to (\iota \to \ast)) \to \ast)$, and so on. So it seems pretty simple, and I understand there's some trick to handle quantifiers as well. Is this the right idea?

Comment: Yep, that's basically it. The definition given for universal quantification, namely: $\forall_\alpha(P)\equiv (P=(\lambda x:\alpha.\mathsf{T}))$ suffices for all orders. The only thing that changes is $\alpha$. Practical realizations, like the systems I mentioned, typically support parametric polymorphism so $\alpha$ would be a type variable and $\forall$ would be a single function that could be instantiated for each type. Second-order quantification, for example, being when $\alpha=\iota\to *$, though $\alpha=\iota\to\iota$ corresponds to quantification over functions.

Comment: I really don't get their definition of $\mathsf{T}$ and $\mathsf{F}$, which I need to define quantifiers. These are different than the primitive constants `true` and `false`, which are of boolean type $\ast$. Instead, we have $\mathsf{T}$ defined as $(\lambda x:\ast .x)=(\lambda x:\ast .x)$. Each side of the equation is an expression of type $(\ast \to \ast)$ (right?), and so the equality yields an expression of type $((\ast \to \ast) \to ((\ast \to \ast) \to \ast))$, which is I guess what $\mathsf{T}$ is. Why do it like this? What does this mean?

Comment: $(\lambda x:*.x)$ is the identity function on $*$. The definition of $\mathsf{T}$ is just asking is the identity function equal to itself which is of course true by reflexivity. $=$ always returns a Boolean (i.e. a value of type $*$).

Comment: That much I understand, but why define $\mathsf{T}$ like that? Why not just define $\mathsf{T}$ as the primitive boolean value `true` directly, expressed as a primitive constant element of $\ast$?

Comment: $\mathsf{F}$ is defined even weirder - as $(\lambda x: \ast . \mathsf{T}) = (\lambda x: \ast . x)$. If we expand the first term out using the definition of $\mathsf{T}$, we get $(\lambda x: \ast . ((\lambda x: \ast . x) = (\lambda x: \ast . x))) = (\lambda x: \ast . x)$. So we're asking if the identity function on $x$ is equal to the function that takes $x$ and returns an equality asking if the identity function is equal to itself. A bit confused by what they're getting at there...

Comment: It's just minimalism. There's nothing gained by explicitly adding constants, and you have to do additional work to assert that they correspond to the appropriate things. You don't want $\mathsf{T}=\mathsf{T}$ to be $\mathsf{F}$ or worse some third value. The definition of $\mathsf{F}$ is asking whether a constant function equals a non-constant function which won't be true unless $\mathsf{T}=\mathsf{F}$. You can also read the definition of $\mathsf{F}$ as $\forall x:*.x$ which you would also hope is not true.

Comment: You can see similar patterns in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1707284/305738) (near the middle, for example the definition of the initial object) which is no surprise as the internal language of a topos is an (intuitionistic) HOL.

Comment: Thanks, will check it out -- FWIW, STT does have $\small{T}$ and $\small{F}$ primitive constants of type $\ast$ which are different from $\textsf{T}$ and $\textsf{F}$ as defined here. They're taking a cue from Henkin's "Theory of Propositional Types" paper, where he defines an altered version of T and F in the manner described, for some syntactic reason that isn't clear to me yet...