# Actually defining functions in Church's simple type theory

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus, type-theory

I've been reading up on [Church's simple type theory](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S157086830700081X) and much of the concepts make sense to me. However, I can't actually figure out how to define functions explicitly using the notation provided.

Notationally, let's say that $\ast$ is the type of boolean truth values, and that $T$ and $F$ are the two constants of that type.

Suppose that I want to define some basic logic gates in STT. The NOT gate is going to be of type $(\ast \to \ast)$, and we can define as $\lambda x:\ast. (x=F)$.

For XNOR, we can curry to obtain a gate of type $(\ast \to (\ast \to \ast))$, which we can define as $\lambda x:\ast. \lambda y:\ast. (x=y)$.

For XOR, we can instead go with $\lambda x:\ast. \lambda y:\ast. ((x=y)=F)$.

But how do we handle something like AND, OR, etc?

In general, is there any way to specify a boolean function by specifying its truth table, or something like that?

EDIT: to be clear, I'm not looking at their embedding of propositional logic into STT further down the page, where they have alternate definitions of $\mathsf{T}$ and $\mathsf{F}$ that differ from the primitive constants $\small{T}$ and $\small{F}$. I'm just trying to figure out how to define functions, period, and I'm using the type $\ast$ for the sake of constructing simple examples.

In short, I want to figure out how to explicitly define a function of type $(\ast \to (\ast \to \ast))$, or $(\ast \to (\ast \to (\ast \to \ast)))$, and so on. How do I do that?

Comment: I have never seen $=$ listed as a primitive in type theory.  Whether 2 lambda expressions can be determined to be equivalent isn't trivial, although it is at least easier for typable lambda expressions IIRC.  Usually $\top$ is defined as $\lambda xy.x$ and $\bot$ is defined as $\lambda xy.y$ (thus the $* \to * \to *$ notation), but this author is doing things weirdly.

Comment: I thought that it was much easier to determine equivalence of two lambda expressions in the typed vs the untyped lambda calculus. As far as the typed lambda calculus goes, Henkin, at least, has explicit T and F constants in [this paper](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm52/fm52123.pdf). The Church booleans you list, as far as I am aware, are typically used in untyped lambda calculus -- even the alternate embedding of $\mathsf{T}$ and $\mathsf{F}$ described in the answer below are not the same as those definitions.

Comment: Are you aware that this "William M. Farmer" is not using the term "Type Theory" (or Simple Type Theory) in the way that everyone else uses it?  What he is really talking about is an attempt to add types to lambda logic.  Modern "type theory" is a method of encoding proofs of FOL in lambda calculus, "simple type theory" refers to the method of encoding proofs of positive propositional logic into lambda calculus.  Not at all what this guy is talking about.

Comment: It seems the same as the article here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_typed_lambda_calculus

Comment: No, what is referred to on the wikipedia page is actually the method of encoding positive propositional proofs into typed lambda calculus.  You notice the page never says something like "and this is the lambda expression representing true...".  That is because propositions there are the types, not the lambda expression being typed.  And don't get me wrong, I think what Farmer is presenting is interesting, maybe even better.  It just is something totally different than simply typed lambda calculus which is based on the curry howard isomorphism.

Comment: @DanielV Constructive type theories and the proposition-as-types appoach is not the only way to use lambda calculi for proofs. If anything *that* use of the term "type theory" is the less justified one as the system described in the article is almost directly a description of Church's "simple theory of types". At any rate, simple type theory (and non-dependently typed extensions thereof) are the basis for the HOL family of theorem provers which have a pedigree as old and significant as constructive type theory.

Comment: @DanielV Also it makes no sense to say the simply typed lambda calculus "is based on the Curry-Howard isomorphism". The simply typed lambda calculus just is. The Curry-Howard correspondence came later and linked two pre-existing systems: intuitionistic propositional logic and its proof theory, and the simply typed lambda calculus.

Comment: @DerekElkins Yes probably should have said "simple type theory" instead of "simply typed lambda calculus" is based on CHI, but the language on all of that stuff is so loose and I was quite clear what I was talking about so I don't think there is a misunderstanding.  Anyway, the author is using Type Theory in a way that no one today uses it, and even if you think it is better, the poster needs to be made aware of the distinction.

Comment: @DanielV The OP [has been made aware of the distinctions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2471373/305738). STT is not based on CHI. If someone said they were proving things in "simple type theory", I'd definitely assume they meant this. If they said they were proving things in the "simply typed lambda calculus", I'd probably still think they meant something like this, as the STLC corresponds to a rather impoverished logic from a CHI perspective.

Comment: @DanielV I will give you that most people talk about "higher-order logic" rather than "simple type theory", but these systems definitely fall under the umbrella of "type theory". STT *is* a STLC. It's just being used in a different way. I do agree that referring to STT as just "type theory" would be confusing, but that's not what the OP did. The OP referred to "Church's simple type theory" which is a much more specific reference (and of course the OP linked to a paper describing what was intended by that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper gives a definition of AND and OR when it describes the embedding of propositional logic into STT. In particular, AND was defined as:
$$A_*\land B_* \equiv (\lambda f:* \to * \to *.f(\mathsf{T})(\mathsf{T}))=(\lambda f:*\to*\to *.f(A_*)(B_*))$$

Given $\neg$ and $\land$, we can define the other classical propositional connectives as usual which is what they proceed to do.

You can understand this definition as $$A_*\land B_*\equiv \langle\mathsf{T},\mathsf{T}\rangle = \langle A_*, B_* \rangle$$
where $\langle A_*, B_* \rangle$ represents the pair of $A_*$ and $B_*$. Of course, the calculus presented doesn't have pairs, so a [Church-encoded representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_pairs) is used instead. You could then, if you like, directly encode OR as the Church-encoded form of $A_*\lor B_* \equiv\langle\mathsf{F},\mathsf{F}\rangle\neq\langle A_*,B_*\rangle$.

Alternatively, you can use the $\mathsf{if}$ construct defined via definite description to simply define whichever Boolean function you want via cases, though I'd personally prefer not relying on definite description.

You can also peruse the definitions used in implementations, such as this one from HOL Light: https://github.com/jrh13/hol-light/blob/7ea931a7d9925fa4abaa14767ba2510c0ad28c62/bool.ml#L97 You can see that it is the definition above.

Comment: I think I responded to this in the comment section of the other question, but the $\textsf{T}$ and $\textsf{F}$ that they're using there are not the same as the $\small{T}$ and $\small{F}$ that they treat as primitive boolean constants earlier in the paper. They're actually just using Henkin's technique from [this paper](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm52/fm52123.pdf). Here, he denotes the actual Boolean constant by $T$, whereas the thing they're calling $\mathsf{T}$ he calls $T^n$, and likewise with $F$ and $F^n$. (cont'd)

Comment: Beyond that I'm really just trying to get the basics of how to define functions, avoiding all of these complex meta-logical embeddings for the moment. $\ast$ is a primitive type with domain equal to $\{\small{T}, \small{F}\}$, and $(\ast \to \ast)$ is likewise well defined. Is there some way to modify your answer to handle these basic cases?

Comment: In short, the question really is: I want to define explicitly the truth table for some function of type $(\ast \to (\ast \to \ast))$. How do I do this?

Comment: There's nothing meta-logical going on. $$\lambda A:*.\lambda B:*.(\lambda f:*\to*\to*.f((\lambda x.*.x)=(\lambda x:*.x))((\lambda x.*.x)=(\lambda x:*.x)))=(\lambda f:*\to*\to*.f(A)(B))$$ is a term of STT. $\mathsf{T}$ and $\mathsf{F}$ are terms of STT. $T$ and $F$ are elements of the semantic domain; they are not terms of STT. You can define the meaning of STT with a collection of (syntactic) rules, i.e. proof theoretically. You don't need the semantics at all to understand or define STT. (Indeed, a set-theoretic semantics is arguably overly narrow-minded.)

Comment: You define a function of type $*\to*\to*$ by writing a lambda term for it. The lambda terms *are* the syntax of STT. They are not a meta-notation.

Comment: The article cited says that a constant $c$ counts as a valid STT expression of type $\tau(c)$, and says that $\small{T}$ and $\small{F}$ are the two constants of type $\ast$. Henkin treats it the same way, and distinguishes between $T$ and $T^n$. Both papers appear to say that constant are valid expressions and that the Boolean type has two constants. Am I interpreting that wrong?

Comment: I don't see where the paper states $T$ and $F$ are constants of type $*$. That is, at no point does it state that $T$ and $F$ are in $\mathcal{C}$. Indeed, unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean by $T$ and $F$, they are only ever referred to as elements in the semantic domain and can be literally any two distinct sets whatsoever. (I've been assuming you mean the $T$ and $F$ from $D_*=\{T,F\}$.) As I said in the other question, you *can* add constants of type $*$, but you run the risk of allowing too many values of type $*$ if you aren't careful to equate them to the intended meanings.

Comment: Ok, I get it - the paper only says that $\ast$ is the type of truth values, but doesn’t specify what those truth values must be. You could have more than two truth values if you want. The different languages of STT then specify what the constants are, and what type each constant is, and hence each language specifies what constants exist of type $\ast$. The structures that the paper calls “standard models” and “general models” are defined as having two constants of type $\ast$, and hence two truth types, but you could also work with three truth types, or four, or so on. Is this the idea?

Comment: If you left the semantics as stated, adding a constant of type $*$ would correspond to a propositional variable like in propositional logic. You wouldn't know whether it was (interpreted as) true or false, but you would know that it was one or the other. Put another way, a constant of type $*$ is a nullary relation symbol. Syntactically, you'd have an elimination rule on $*$, that would look like $\mathsf{if}$, to ensure that there are only two values. My comment about "too many values" was misleading to the point of being wrong. Supporting non-Boolean logics is a small but profound change.

Comment: Instead, I should have said that the constants are non-logical constants whereas the terms representing "true" and "false" have specific significance to the logic (i.e. truth and falsity should, in general [i.e. even in FOL, say], be viewed as nullary logical connectives). Simply positing two constants of type $*$ doesn't mean they should be interpreted as distinct values and (as I mentioned in the other question) doesn't tell us which (if any) should correspond to truth vs falsity. We could add *logical* constants with special rules and that were treated specially by the semantics, though.

Comment: OK, I see. Let's just clear this up and make it simple - suppose I just decide that I want two logical constants, called $x$ and $y$, of type $\ast$. So within that language, suppose I want to define the function that takes two elements of type $\ast$, and returns $y$ only if both are $y$, or otherwise returns $x$. It's clear that this will be of type $(\ast \to (\ast \to \ast))$. But how do I explicitly define this function using lambda terms? I don't care about the logical interpretation - I'm just looking to understand, syntactically, how to define very basic functions, that's all.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't even say "logical" constants. I just want to have two constants, $x$ and $y$, of type $\ast$. They could stand for "my foot" and "a car outside," or something. Just two different elements, with no other interpretation at all, and trying to see how to actually specify functions from that.

Comment: As I stated in the answer and the comments, the thing that makes the logic classical is the elimination rule for $*$ which looks like $\mathsf{if}$. The function you describe could be written using $\mathsf{if}$, assuming $x=\mathsf{T}$ and $y=\mathsf{F}$, as: $$\lambda a:*.\lambda b:*.\mathsf{if}(a,x,\mathsf{if}(b,x,y))$$ Again, at the level of syntax constants don't "stand for" anything. The interpretation via the semantics of terms of type $*$ in the syntax is required to be one of $T$ or $F$, but $T$ and $F$ can be "my foot" and "a car outside". You continually mix syntax and semantics.

Comment: Syntactically, the special rules for $\mathsf{T}$ and $\mathsf{F}$ are $\mathsf{if}(\mathsf{T},M,N)=M$, $\mathsf{if}(\mathsf{F},M,N)=N$, and $\mathsf{if}(x,\mathsf{T},\mathsf{F})=x$. Semantically, adding logical constants means adding constant terms, say $t$ and $f$, where you require for *every* semantics, i.e. every interpretation $I$, that $I(t)=T$ and $I(f)=F$. A non-logical constant can vary in each semantics. At the syntactic level, this means we don't know which of $M$ or $N$ $\mathsf{if}(x,M,N)$ is for a non-logical constant $x$ unless we can prove it equals $\mathsf{T}$/$\mathsf{F}$.

Comment: For arbitrary terms $x$ and $y$ (of actually any type), you can define $\lambda a:\alpha.\lambda b:\alpha.\mathsf{if}(a=y,\mathsf{if}(b=y,y,x),x)$ where $x,y:\alpha$ for a function that behaves as you state. (With regards to my previous comment, there are additional rules for $\mathsf{if}$, commuting conversions, to deal with cases like $\mathsf{if}(\mathsf{if}(-,-,-),-,-)$. At least, if $\mathsf{if}$ were taken as primitive.) One of the benefits of avoiding using $\mathsf{if}$ is that definitions not using it may hold also in the non-classical case.

Comment: OK, maybe this is what I'm missing. What type are $\mathsf{T}$ and $\mathsf{F}$ here? Are they of type $\ast$? Because in [this page](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory-church/) they use exactly the same trick to define what they call $T_\omicron$ and $F_\omicron$, but these are of type $\omicron$, which is the same as what this author denotes type $\ast$.

Comment: For instance, in this comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2470986/type-theory-vs-higher-order-logic/2471373#comment5133275_2471373), I thought that $\mathsf{T}$ was of type $((\ast \to \ast) \to ((\ast \to \ast) \to \ast))$, and I've been running on that assumption. Have I been wrong about that?

Comment: Yes!! I misunderstood the type of the equality operator. I thought equality was basically a curried function with two inputs, so that the expression $(E_1 : \ast = E_2 : \ast)$ has type $(\ast \to (\ast \to \ast))$. But I'm wrong: the expression has type $\ast$, as stated in the paper. So all is right with the world: $\mathsf{T}$ and $\mathsf{F}$ have type $\ast$. Phew!