# Lambda calculus combined with first order logic notation (quantifiers, propositional connectives, and set notation)

Tags: logic, quantifiers, lambda-calculus, type-theory

I understand that Lambda Calculus does not traditionally admit the notation of first-order logic and set-theory, such as the quantifiers $\forall$ and $\exists$, the propositional connectives $\vee, \implies,...$, and set notation, such as $x \in S$. However, as a working mathematician, it is only natural to want to combine these formalisms into statements such as

> $$ \forall x:\mathbb{N} \left(f(x) \in S\right)$$ where $f = \lambda z:\mathbb{N}. 2z$ , and $S = \{n:\mathbb{N}\mid\ 2 | n\}$ .

Is there some studied logic system in which statements like the one above can be formalized naturally?

Comment: The links in this post have references that address your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486170/actually-defining-functions-in-churchs-simple-type-theory

Comment: Universal quantification is defined in the obvious way, $$(\forall x. Px) \iff (P = \lambda  y.\top)$$ defining $\top$ and the other operators is actually the demanding part.

Comment: @DanielV: What about set notation?

Comment: A set is just a unary relation.  Honestly I'm not the person to ask.  Look at who was active on the other question, and @ping them to let them know you have a similar question.

Comment: @DanielV: and propositional connectives?

Comment: That is literally the entire content of the other question.

Comment: @DanielV You can't use `@foo` to cause a notification to someone who is not involved in a question (unless I'm seriously misunderstanding something). I hope it goes without saying that it would definitely be considered poor form to make a comment on some other question for this purpose.

Comment: @DanielV: Even if there is a way to define all these notations in lambda calculus, is it easy to actually use them and reason with them? Take for instance [the motivation behind the system of natural deduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction#Motivation). It's not that logic was not sufficiently formalized before, but there was a need to create a system were the actual practice of writing formal proofs was convenient and "natural".

Comment: @DanielV: And this is what I am looking for: a system where formal proofs involving functions, sets, types, numbers and logical quantification can be carried out naturally and conveniently.

Comment: I guess it is fair to say that the system is more complicated than natural deduction, but much simpler than natural deduction plus set theory.  And IMO, what matters more is the ability to create your own tools in the logic, moreso than whether the logic provides those tools as primitives.

Comment: See [abstraction operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_abstraction) for some info and (few) references.

Comment: See [Frege's Theorem](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-theorem/) for an example of extensive use.

Comment: @EvanAad There are mechanized proof assistants for languages based on set theory like [Mizar](http://mizar.org/), indirectly [MetaMath](http://us.metamath.org/), and though it hasn't really been aimed at mathematical problems (as opposed to a subset of CS problems), [TLAPS](http://tla.msr-inria.inria.fr/tlaps/content/Home.html) might be a third option. I guess I should mention there's also Isabelle/ZF.

Comment: There are also Coq and Agda which are based on type-theoretic mathematical foundations - which might be a better fit to the typed lambda expressions you were using in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [HOL](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S157086830700081X)-like approach as described in the link given by DanielV, subsets given by the axiom of specification are just modeled as predicates. Your whole expression becomes $\forall(\lambda x\!:\!\mathbb{N}.S(f(x)))$ (or more compactly: $\forall (S\circ f)$) where $S\equiv\lambda n\!:\!\mathbb{N}.(2|n)$.  You can look at the systems [HOL4](https://hol-theorem-prover.org/), [HOL Light](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jrh13/hol-light/), and [Isabelle/HOL](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/documentation.html) for mechanized proof assistants for this approach.

An alternative approach mentioned in the other question but not elaborated on there is a propositions-as-types approach.  This approach is usually used in a constructive setting with a dependently typed lambda calculus. In this approach, we model a statement by a type, and the proof of the statement is witnessed by providing a value of that type. This is the  approach used by mechanized proof assistants like [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/), [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php), or [LEAN](https://leanprover.github.io/).

In this case, we might have a type like $\prod_{x:\mathbb{N}}S(f(x))$. $S$ would look the same except now $2|n$ would need to stand for a type. There are a variety of ways of accomplishing this. For example, we could have an (explicitly defined) function (i.e. an algorithm) $\mathtt{divides} : \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{B}$ where $\mathbb{B}$ is the type of Booleans with values $\mathtt{True}$ and $\mathtt{False}$. Then $(m|n)\equiv(\mathtt{divides}(m,n)=_\mathbb{B}\mathtt{True})$. Actually proving that $\prod_{x:\mathbb{N}}S(f(x))$ holds would mean actually providing a lambda term of that type. It may be as simple as $\lambda x\!:\!\mathbb{N}.\mathtt{refl}_\mathtt{True}$ depending on the exact definition of $\mathtt{divides}$, but it could easily require more equational reasoning than this. ($\mathtt{refl}_x$ is the value that "proves", in the above sense, that $x=x$.)

To address one of your comments, both approaches above have been extensively used in practice as you can see from the applications of the proof assistants mentioned. This is a personal opinion, but I would go so far to say that even using either of these approaches by hand is more natural and feasible that (formally!) using set theory. Of course, the latter approach is, as I said, usually used as a constructive type theory which makes a profound difference including making some results much harder to prove (and, of course, making some results impossible to prove). (Classical) HOL is definitely much closer (in fact *very* close to) "standard" math/set theory.

Comment: Could you please add a link (links) to some of the relevant literature, specifically, (Classical) HOL?

Comment: I added a link (among others) to [The Seven Virtues of Simple Type Theory](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S157086830700081X) which is the paper mentioned in the other question. It is referenced by the HOL4 documentation. You can look at its references for more details; it's more of an introduction and not super-formal meta-theoretically. Of course, any of the implementations I linked to (or there are a few others) also have tutorials, documentation, and complete and unambiguous descriptions of the languages they implement and how things like connectives are derived.

Comment: Are all those systems you referenced actually based on the typed lambda calculus the poster is describing, or are they actually based on curry-howard style type systems?

Comment: @DanielV The OP isn't really specific about any particular lambda calculus. It's quite likely (classical) HOL is closest to what the OP would want assuming they want to do more or less "standard" mathematics. All the "HOL" systems are examples of this. The other systems "Agda, Coq, LEAN" are constructive type theories and are explicitly alternative approaches. The answer is a bit heavy on describing these systems since they work in a less familiar way. While the constructive type theory approach is probably not what the OP wants, it also allows a natural formulation of the given statement.